# RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied) Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, sdk, runtimeexception

I am getting this error while running any android applications, both on Android Studio, and Eclipse.

```
RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\UserName\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\android-palette\v1\layout_palette.xml (Access is denied)
```

[The error in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH19t.jpg)

I searched for solutions all over SO, But didn't get one matching to my error. I am getting rendering issues with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the file layout_palette.xml writable and it should work.

To make the file writable, right click the file and choose properties. Click the security tab. Click the edit button, check the write box and then apply.

Comment: @RosyWilliams are you logged in your computer with admin rights when changing the file to writable?